# Error al mostrar una imagen con JSON en Android

Tags: android, php, mysql, json

Que tal, estoy tratando de mostrar imágenes en un `ImageView` desde una base de datos [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) en Android.

Me muestra lo siguiente:

```
org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

**Código**

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class ShowImage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private String imagesJSON;

    private static final String JSON_ARRAY ="result";
    private static final String IMAGE_URL = "url";

    private JSONArray arrayImages= null;

    private int TRACK = 0;

    private static final String IMAGES_URL = "http://misitio.com/showimage.php";

    private Button buttonFetchImages;
    private Button buttonMoveNext;
    private Button buttonMovePrevious;
    private ImageView imageView;
    private String TAG="ShowImage";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_image);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        buttonFetchImages = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFetchImages);
        buttonMoveNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonNext);
        buttonMovePrevious = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPrev);
        buttonFetchImages.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonMoveNext.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonMovePrevious.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    private void extractJSON(){
        try {
              //Aquí marca el error
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(imagesJSON);
            arrayImages = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);
            Log.e(TAG,"====:  "+arrayImages);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void showImage(){
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = arrayImages.getJSONObject(TRACK);
            getImage(jsonObject.getString(IMAGE_URL));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }

    private void moveNext(){
        if(TRACK < arrayImages.length()){
            TRACK++;
            showImage();
        }
    }

    private void movePrevious(){
        if(TRACK>0){
            TRACK--;
            showImage();
        }
    }



    private void getAllImages() {
        class GetAllImages extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(ShowImage.this, "Fetching Data...","Please Wait...",true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                imagesJSON = s;
                extractJSON();
                showImage();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String uri = params[0];
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(uri);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    String json;
                    while((json = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                        sb.append(json+"\n");
                    }

                    return sb.toString().trim();

                }catch(Exception e){
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        GetAllImages gai = new GetAllImages();
        gai.execute(IMAGES_URL);
    }

    private void getImage(String urlToImage){
        class GetImage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>{
            ProgressDialog loading;
            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
                URL url = null;
                Bitmap image = null;

                String urlToImage = params[0];
                try {
                    url = new URL(urlToImage);
                    image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return image;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(ShowImage.this,"cargando imagen...","Espere...",true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
                loading.dismiss();
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
        GetImage gi = new GetImage();
        gi.execute(urlToImage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == buttonFetchImages) {
            getAllImages();
        }
        if(v == buttonMoveNext){
            moveNext();
        }
        if(v== buttonMovePrevious){
            movePrevious();
        }
    }
}
```

Al parecer no está recibiendo en lel formato que debe y me señala el error en la parte en la que lo extrae:

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(imagesJSON);
```

Otro dato es que quizá esté mal en la parte donde armo el `JSON`, en otras ocasiones he tenido este error pero era debido a espacios extras en la consulta y cosas así. :

**showimage.php**

```
    <?php
 define('HOST','misitio.com');
 define('USER','usuario');
 define('PASS','pass');
 define('DB','test');

 $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('Unable to Connect');

 $sql = "select id from imagenes";

 $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);


 $result = array();

 $url = "http://misitio.com/showimage.php?id=";
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
 array_push($result,array('url'=>$url.$row['id']));
 }

 echo json_encode(array("result"=>$result));

 mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Esto me muestra lo siguiente, veo muy sospechoso los `\/`:

```
{"result":[{"url":"http:\/\/misitio.com\/showimage.php?id=1"},{"url":"http:\/\/misitio.comr\/showimage.php?id=2"},{"url":"http:\/\/misitio.com\/showimage.php?id=3"}]}
```

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Si estas recibiendo este error:

```
> org.json.JSONException: Value <html><body><script of type
> java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Significa que tratas de crear un objeto a partir de una entidad html, lo cual es incorrecto, como lo comentas, no se esta recibiendo el formato correcto .json.

Asegura recibir el correcto formato .json.

En cuanto a los `\/`  no debes preocuparte, no son ningún problema, es una forma de codificar ó "escapar" caracteres especiales:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn921889.aspx